# Without calculating the partial derivatives, explain why sin x cosh y and cos x sinh y are harmonic functions in C.

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

It could be simple if I was allowed to use partial Derivatives.
Without calculating partial derivative I don't know how to prove that it's harmonic. Can someone please amswer this question?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if $x,y\in\Bbb R$,\begin{align}\sin(x+yi)&=\sin(x)\cos(yi)+\cos(x)\sin(yi)\\&=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+\cos(x)\sinh(y)i\end{align}and therefore your functions are the real part and the imaginary part of a holomorphic function. Therefore, they are harmonic.